# Error in user access control in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm making a blogging app; each user will be able to post their ideas and only posted user can able to delete or update the post.

```
exports.verifyOwn = function (req, res, next) {
 if (User._id === req.decoded._doc.postedBy) {
   next();
 } else {
   var err = new Error('You do not have administrative privileges!');
   err.status = 401;
   return next(err);
 } 
 }
```

this my verifiaction code. how can i make that possible to delte the post by their own users

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
   title:{
   type:String,
   required:true
   },
   image:{
   type:String,
   required:true
    },
   meta:{
   type:String,
   required:true
  },
  story:{
   type:String,
   required:true
   },
   likes:{
   type:Number,
   min:0,
   required:true
  },
   postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User' 
   },
   comments:[commentSchema]
    },
   {
     timestamps: true
    });
```

and this is my user schema

```
var User = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
OauthId: String,
OauthToken: String,
firstname: {
  type: String,
    default: ''
},
lastname: {
  type: String,
    default: ''
},
biodata: {
  type: String,
  default: ''
},
admin:{
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just check the id stored on a session. Use a library like [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) to track a session.